# Workaround for vertical scrolling in Vis.js

Tags: javascript, timeline, vis.js

After implementing timeline with vis.js I found out that it currently cannot handle situation when there are too many groups for it to fit the canvas. It [currently doesn't provide](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/273) a vertical scrollbar and I couldn't make it scrollable with dragging.

Is there some known temporary workaround for it? Some manual manipulation basing on events perhaps? Aside from that vis.js works great for my and it would be a shame if I had to rewrite everything into other timeline library just because of that one thing.

Comment: OP could you let me know how you resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably just add this to your CSS:

```
.vis-timeline {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Good point! I tried that but it didn't exactly work... but `overflow-y: scroll;` on `#my-timeline-container` did the trick!

Comment: on what container did you add it too its positioned absolute and its height is the size of the container so dont know how that would work.  if it does work i'd love to know what element to add it too :)

Comment: There was `this._timelineId = "my-timeline-container"` in my config. So I added the CSS to the container that I choose as top-level timeline container for vis.js.